# How can I establish "shared" variables for all Bash instances on a machine?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

How can I establish these shared variables forever on all Bash instances?

```
export PATH=/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-5.5/bin:$PATH
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-5.5/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: Why is this tagged C?

Comment: And why is this tagged with NVIDIA, CUDA, and theano?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` it seems you are using Mac. You can put these in `~/.bashrc`. If your current `$SHELL` is `bash` then each time you open a Terminal it should execute those lines and they will be available to read/modify later. e.g. `echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: /etc/profile.d/ exists on mac too.  it applies to all users as opposed to .bashrc which is user specific.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll want to put this logic in a file located in `/etc/profile.d/`, assuming you're using some Unix/Linux based distribution.